# Minimizing the sum of scares by variegate two constants of a given function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I´ve checked several posts, but i didn´t find the best or fasted solution for my problem. I´ve got a list of values and a function. Now i would like to find the best solution by variegating the "C1" and "C2" constants.

Is there a package to easily implement this?

My "Datatable" looks like this:

[image]

The 7,12... is just an example. It´s the sum of the locale failures and thats the value that has to be minimized. I would like to find C1 and C2 that gave the "best" solution.

**EDIT: The values in the green box are the values that i measured**

Comment: Mathematically speaking, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Finding C1 and C2 constants that minimize the sum of the locale failure.

Comment: Take a look at [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).  It does nonlinear least-squares fitting.

Comment: If you're already in Excel, why don't you use [Excel solver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) right away?